# unable to read file using R in databricks

Tags: r, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to read a hash file from a blob storage whis is already having a mount point
i.e /mnt/home.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvUpR.png)

I can see that the files are located under the same mount point:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4bmb.png)

I am using R to read the file in databricks with the query as below

```
%r 
install.packages("qs")
data <- qs::read("/mnt/home/country/002273b76c24cb37f3c3f1")
head(data)
```

however i am coming across the following error message:

```
Error in qs::qread("dbfs:/mnt/home/country/002273b76c24cb37f3c3f1") : 
  Failed to open dbfs:/mnt/home/country/002273b76c24cb37f3c3f1. Check file path.
Some(<code style = 'font-size:10p'> Error in qs::qread(&quot;dbfs:/mnt/home/country/002273b76c24cb37f3c3f1;): Failed to open dbfs:/mnt/home/country/002273b76c24cb37f3c3f1. Check file path. </code>)
Error in qs::qread("dbfs:/mnt/home/country/002273b76c24cb37f3c3f1"): Failed to open dbfs:/mnt/home/country/002273b76c24cb37f3c3f1. Check file path.
```

can i get some advice in fixing the issue

Comment: 'I am trying to read a hash file from a blob storage', Is the above same when you tried reading any other format file?

Comment: no for a csv file its working i was able to read

Answer (score 0):

you need to append `/dbfs` to use local file API - see [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/files/index.html#understand-default-locations-with-examples):

```r
data <- qs::qread("/dbfs/mnt/home/country/002273b76c24cb37f3c3f1")
```

But it may not work with mounts (depends on the mount type) - in this case you will need to copy file from mount to local disk by using [dbutils](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html):

```r
dbutils.fs.cp("/mnt/home/country/002273b76c24cb37f3c3f1", "file:/tmp/my_file")
data <- qs::qread("/tmp/my_file")
```

Comment: i used dbfs before but was still not working

Comment: i copied the file but even after that i am getting error as 
Error : 'read' is not an exported object from 'namespace:qs'
Some(<code style = 'font-size:10p'> Error: 'read' is not an exported object from 'namespace:qs' </code>)
Error: 'read' is not an exported object from 'namespace:qs'

Comment: I'm not familiar with that package - open its documentation to find a correct name. I've copied the code from your example

Comment: but from error, it looks like it should be `qread` not `read`

Comment: ohh yeah i am able to read now but the issue is i have a huge file of 1TB so is copying a good option here? I understand we can use recursive = True. but will that be helpful for such a huge file

Comment: copying of 1TB file will most probably fail. But how it will be handled by the `qs::qread` ?

Comment: well at the moment i am ready for one location but the over all file size is 1TB which i will be reading country wise and then use it further. However the files are in GBs so wanted to understand if thats a good choice

Comment: there are a lot of files in the directory /mnt/home/country/  wondering if it will work only for one file at a time or all the files in the directory as i tried to copy all the files but when i tried to ready it was showing an error as 
Error in qs::qread("/tmp/my_file3") :   basic_filebuf::underflow error reading the file: Is a directory
Some(<code style = 'font-size:10p'> Error in qs::qread(&quot;/tmp/my_file3&quot;): basic_filebuf::underflow error reading the file: Is a directory </code>)
Error in qs::qread("/tmp/my_file3"): basic_filebuf::underflow error reading the file: Is a directory

Comment: it heavily dependent on your `qs` package. I don't know anything about it